# Chrome extension for bookmarking links?

Tags: chrome, bookmark, hyperlink

In Firefox, you can bookmark a page via a hyperlink by right-clicking the link and selecting "Bookmark This Link". Unfortunately, Chrome doesn't have this feature, which I love so freaking much and use a good amount of the time.

Is there a Chrome extension that can give me this feature?

I would prefer it to be able to run on both Chrome for Windows and Chrome OS, but I would at *least* like it to work on one of these.

#### Specs

1. Windows

   - **Make & Model**: HP Compaq dc5700 SFF Base
   - **Operating System**: Windows 7 Pro SP1 x64
   - **Browser**: Google Chrome, v44.0.2403.130 m (64-bit, Stable)(Up-to-date)
2. Chromebook

   - **Make & Model**: HP Chromebook 11
   - **Operating System**: Google Chrome OS, v44.0.2403.125 (Stable)(Up-to-date)
   - **Browser**: *Same as OS*.

Comment: Do either answer solve your issue, or are you still missing something which hinders you in accepting an answer? If so, please clarify

Comment: No, I just haven't been on the site for a little while. Lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found some extensions which seems to do the right stuff:

- **[Right Click Bookmark](//chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/right-click-bookmark/jeccccjfpjoheejopfjmhcbkdeiohfgg)** - When installing it asks for a folder to store the new bookmarks in, adds *Add Bookmark* to context menu, which opens a dialog window asking for bookmark title with a default of the link title
- [Contextmenu Bookmark Link](//chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/contextmenu-bookmark-link/oojdfdpcddiefnhfhiblmhgjgmafkhkm) – Adds a context menu *Add Bookmark*, which saves the link into the *Other Bookmarks* folder using the URL as the title
- [Link to Bookmark](//chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-to-bookmark/mhdidjpeopgpmlknlinmkplhbgopjegj) – Most of the user interface is Chinese(?), but offers a possibility to specify folder, and to add links with `undefined` as title for the saved link
- [Link Bookmarker](//chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-bookmarker/gafefghkifeldfajneckpibmedjjcdkl) – Adds *Add Bookmark* to context menu, and adds the bookmark directly to the bookmark toolbar, but doesn't conserve the title, uses the URL
- [Bookmark This](//chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-this/cdgfikopcomgllhdlknlfgblhmhemljn) – Adds *Bookmark This* to the context menu, but can't see the result anywhere...

My suggestion is to use [Right Click Bookmark](//chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/right-click-bookmark/jeccccjfpjoheejopfjmhcbkdeiohfgg) for adding bookmarks to single links, as it preserves the title of the link, and you are able to specify the folder when installing the extension. In addition install the [LinkClump](//chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkclump/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj), as suggested in my other answer, to allow for selecting an area with links and storing all the links at once.

Comment: Wow, thanks! :) Yeah, I don't have any need for LinkClump, but I'll **definitely** look into Right Click Bookmark!

Answer (score 2):

After some searching I found two alternate workarounds, which does have some of the functionality you are looking for.

### Linkclump extension

This extension can select a block in a web page and then either open all the links or *bookmark* the links.

To get this to work do the following:

- Install the [LinkClump](//chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkclump/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj) extension
- Change configuration so that the action is *Bookmarked* and not the default *Opened as New Tabs*
- Save, and potentially close the configuration window

When you now hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag the selection box over one or more links, it will add the links to a a newly created folder within the *Other bookmarks* folder named *LinkClump* .

### Using the bookmark manager

I haven't found an extension to do this, but I've found kind of a workaround:

- First open the bookmark manager in a new window/tab
- Find the link, right-click, and select "Copy link address"
- Goto bookmark manager, hover over a bookmark folder, right-click and select paste

It's not as elegant as the firefox solution, and it doesn't keep the title of the link, but maybe it is a little better than opening the link and then hitting the bookmark button.

---

Neither of these are just what you ask for, but maybe better than your current options...

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame Chrome doesn't have that option. :/ Nevertheless, it's sort of expected with Chrome; it's kind of known for being comparatively restricted. For what I have available to me, though, thank you! :D